Simplify $ (\log m)^{\log \log m} \geq n $ in terms of m.
I'm getting
$$ m^{\log \log m } \geq 2^{n} $$
so
$$ m^{\log m } \geq 2^{2^{n}} $$
so
$$ m^{m} \geq 2^{2^{2^{n}}} $$
so
$$ m \log m \geq {2^{2^{n}}} $$.
Is there a better way to do this? What are some hints for approaching these kinds of expressions?
What would be a super rigorous way to conclude $ m \geq n $ from this inequality?

From $m^{\log \log m } \geq 2^{n}$ does not follows $m^{\log m } \geq 2^{2^{n}}$

Even the first step is suspect. Assuming $\log$ means $\log_2,$ it is true that $$2^{(\log m^{\log\log m})}\geq 2^n.$$ But the left side is not equal to $$(2^{\log m})^{\log\log m}.$$ Exponentiaton is not associative.

I will assume that the base of the logs is $b>1$, perhaps $b=2$, $b=e$, or $b=10$. Define $u=\log m$. I'll assume that $u=\log m>1$ so that $\log\log m$ in the title is positive. I first assume that $n> 1$ (see below for $0<n\le1$).
The equation in the question title says $u^{\log u}\ge n$. Take the log of both sides to get:
\begin{align}
(\log u)^2 &\ge \log n & \text{since log is increasing for $b>1$}\\ 
\log u &\ge \sqrt{\log n} & \text{by assumption $n>1$ and $u>1$}\\
u = \log m &\ge b^{\sqrt{\log n}} & \text{since $b^x$ is increasing for $b>1$}\\
m &\ge b^{b^\sqrt{\log n}}
\end{align}
If $0<n\le1$ then $\log n\le0$, so the equation $(\log u)^2 \ge \log n$ is true for any $u$, and therefore any $m$.
